# Insert a position and check for geofence entry exit in postgres with postgis

Tags: postgis, geofencing

Is it possible to insert a position, and any related geofence entry exits for that position in just one query in postgres (9.6) with postgis (2.3.2)?

For example given tables `users`, `positions`, `fences` and `events`:

```
user_id | name 
1       | bob  
2       | jane  

position_id | user_id | lat        | lon          
1           | 2       | 33.1261983 | -117.3138087 

fence_id | geometry
1        | 0101000021E610000096F92563F71F63402664979471963EC1
2        | 0101000022E610000096F92563F71F63402664979471963EC2

event_id | type  | position_id | fence_id
1        | entry | 1           | 1
2        | entry | 1           | 2
3        | exit  | 1           | 3
```

I'm currently doing it in multiple steps:

Insert the position:

```
insert into positions (user_id, lat, lon) values ($1, $2, $3)
returning id as new_position_id
```

Get the fences for the new position and the previous position, with $2 param being the value returned from the insert above

```
with current_and_previous_position as (
    select id from positions where user_id = $1 and id < $2
    union all (select $2)
)
select * from 
positions  
join fences on ST_Contains(geometry, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(lon, lat), 4326)) 
where positions.id in (select id from current_and_previous_position)
```

Then the next step is some Node.js code that takes the fences list and calculates if there are any entries or exits:

```
var entries = getEntriesFor(user, position, positionFences);
var exits = getExitsFor(user, position, positionFences);
```

And finally, I save the entries and exits (where $1 is the entry + exit lists concatenated together):

```
insert into events (type, position_id, fence_id)
select * from json_populate_recordset(null::events, $1)
```

This works, but takes too many individual steps, and 3 database operations for each and every position received.

Is it possible to do this in one single DB operation that inserts both the position, and the geofence entries and exits?